# How To Write a Query That Is Based On Three Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are my tables. So basically I had to create a bunch of queries that were based off of two tables, which I did easily. The last question is asking to create a table that is based off of three tables, and the problem is I honestly cannot think of a way to reference all of these tables, it seems that there are not enough attributes in each table to reference three different ones.

Does anyone have any idea?

**CRIME**

```
crime_code PK
criminal_code FK
crime_desc
```

**CRIMINAL**

```
crim_code PK
jail_code FK
life_behind_bars
release_date
```

**JAIL**

```
jail_code PK
num_criminals_in_jail
cop_code FK
```

**COP**

```
cop_code
cop_Lname
cop_Fname
cop_phone
```

Comment: Do you know what `PK` and `FK` stand for?

Comment: Primary key and foreign key... Just put that there so who ever read knew.

Comment: What are they for?

Comment: What do you mean? Primary identifies it, and foreign references another table?

Comment: How many `FK`->`PK` pairs can you find in your tables?

Comment: What does all this have to do with the question exactly?

Comment: Everything.  You need to open your eyes and see that all 4 of your tables are related.

Comment: Obviously they are related... I just cannot think of an idea of a query that references more than two. It's really throwing me off for some reason.

Comment: List your two-table queries.

Comment: What are the three tables you need to reference? You could InnerJoin the Three depending on what they are or if they have equal data points, or you could subquery. Need more information to provide an answer. What is the question specifically asking?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have data what we can use to test? What is the expected result? Please read [ask] for more info about how to and what to ask on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM CRIME c
INNER JOIN CRIMINAL cr ON c.criminal_code = cr.crim_code
INNER JOIN JAIL j ON cr.jail_code = j.jail_code
INNER JOIN COP cp ON j.cop_code = cp.cop_code
```

This is a simple select statement with multiple join. The first table CRIME joins to the second table CRIMINAL using the FK of CRIME to join to the PK of CRIMINAL, so on and so on.

Info on joins. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

This is all very basic stuff and can be found with a google search.

Comment: Please also explain the sql query.